# UIImage Not being Set from NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, json

The goal is to pull a image stored as a varbinary in a sql server through a web service that sends a sqlbinary as a JSON to an iphone. I'm having trouble setting the UIImage from the base64binary sent from the JSON. I'm able to convert the binary to NSData but the image is not being set through the data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
            NSDictionary *mealInfo = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            Meal *meal =[[Meal alloc]initWithRestaurant:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"restaurantname"]
                                               mealName:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"itemname"]
                                            description:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"itemdescription"]
                                                   Time:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"mealTime"]
                                                  price:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"itemprice"]];
            //NSString *str = @"data:image/jpg;base64,";
            //str = [str stringByAppendingString:[mealInfo objectForKey:@"itemImage"]];
            //NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

            NSString *str = [mealInfo objectForKey:@"itemImage"];
            NSLog(@"%@", str);

            NSData *d = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:str]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:d];
            [meal setMealImage:image];

                        [meals addObject:meal];

        }
        NSLog(@"%@",[[meals objectAtIndex:0]mealPrice]);
        NSLog(@"This is how many meals %d", meals.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string containing the base 64 encoded is good, your code looks OK. I would look at the `dataFromBase64String` method to see if that is causing the problem.  Here is a version I use based on some else's work:

```
-(NSData *)dataFromBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string{
    if (string.length > 0) {

       //the iPhone has base 64 decoding built in but not obviously. The trick is to
       //create a data url that's base 64 encoded and ask an NSData to load it.
       NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:;base64,%@", string];
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data64URLString]];
        return data;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

You could add a `NSData` category with this method to make its use very convenient.